# what does "?" in ruby means?

Tags: ruby

I want to know it real meaning of it and how to use it exactly.

Another question is about assert I saw

`assert product.valid?  product.errors.full_messages`
and

```
assert product.valid?
```

But I can't find syntax for those assert what does second arg for assert (product.errors.full_messages) means or it is arg for ?

Thanks

Comment: I just got answer about assert, in every assert method last argument (optional) specified message to show when it assert false

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ruby uses specific naming conventions for methods.  It allows you to quickly identify the side effects they may have, or the return type..

These conventions use special markers such as "**!**" and "**?**" at the end of method names. This is uncommon since most programming languages tend to forbid such characters in identifiers, but nevertheless, it is truly part of the method name. (and should not be confused with operators)

- Post fixing "**?**" means that the method returns a boolean. It's a convenient way to replace the "is" prefix. (this convention tends to exist in lisp dialects too)
- Post fixing "**!**" means that the method will modify the instance, and thus won't act on/return a copy.

Note that these are just conventions. In no way you *have to* follow it, but it *is* considered a good practice.

Comment: Just to add to this post in this case the '?' and '!' are actually part of the method name and not operators.

Comment: Just to add that ? and ! are just a convention and not a requirement.

Comment: Truthfully, the purpose of ! mark is to mark a method as special. It doesn’t necessarily mean that it will be destructive or dangerous, but it means that it will require more attention than its alternative. ActiveRecord create! is an example on non destructive use.

Comment: The comments are more accurate than the original response.

Answer (score 3):

It is purely a convention, it has no formal meaning. It isn't unusual for people to get confused by this, since many (most?) languages don't allow characters such as ? and ! in identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

It's just convention to put it on a method that returns a boolean afaik. Rather than making everythign IsSomething.